# How to use Html Drag & Drop API with select element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a system which uses the HTML Drag & Drop API.

If I add the `draggable="true"` attribute to the `select` element, then it does not work as I expect. It is not draggable. When I try to drag it, it just opens the `select` dropdown. I could make it draggable by adding `pointer-events:none` to the CSS, but then the `select` element becomes unavailable.

I need to have the behavior like the standard input element. When I create an input element that has `draggable="true"` then I should be able to click it to write inside it, and I should also be able to press and hold down to drag it somewhere else.

Here is my code snippet:

```html
<div>Works with input: <input type="text" draggable="true" /></div>
<div>
  Does not work with select:
  <select draggable="true">
    <option>Example Option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can, you'd need to add a way, somewhere else, to disable the select, so that it's draggable while disabled, and then enable it back once dropped.

Comment: Why do you need to move the `<select>` independently of the text input? You can make a whole form draggable, assuming you're using a form. Can you use JQuery, or just CSS? you didn't specify.